# SVN,can a single directory/project be commit to two repositories?

Tags: windows, svn

For historical reason I need to commit the same project to two repositories on two different hosts.

Is this possible in SVN?Will there be conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I think svn [Replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) could help what you want. 
from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605441/same-working-copy-of-the-code-with-2-svn-servers/605447#605447)

> use the Relocate  command to connect
>   your working copy with the first
>   repository, commit there, and then
>   relocate to the second repository and
>   commit there as well. Better make a
>   copy of your working copy folder
>   somewhere else first.

notice about the fact 'svn file in a dir is only for 1 repo.'